# Automatic security update fails by unmet dependency

Tags: apt, updates, dependencies

Ubuntu 12.04 - Update manager failed to install security update of some headers. I have tried:
    sudo apt-get -f install
which tries to get dependencies, but initially fails with:

```
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-54_3.2.0-54.82_all.deb
```

followed by many more errors including:
    No space left on device
which is completely rubbish as there is more than 120 gb of space.

Questions:

1. Can I fix this problem?
2. If not, can I at least remove the faulty update so I can get the apt-get and the update manager working again?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-cache clean && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Do you have a separte `/boot` partition?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a seperate /boot partition to me, too. Try uninstalling old and unused kernels, before installing new ones.

Comment: Thanks to all comments above. I have a dual boot installation of Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and having checked, I see there are more than 30 old linux-images, some with status 'deinstall', and some 'install'. However, purging requires apt-get, which immediately finds the unmet dependencies and advises me to fix them, which is the problem I started off with!

Comment: In case anyone is interested this problem is now resolved. You can see an analysis of the problem and its fix on the forums thread: (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177876)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check for old unused kernels is using

```
dpkg -l linux-image* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v $(uname -r)
```

This will display each kernel version except the one you already has installed:

```
dpkg -l linux-image* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v $(uname -r)
linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic
linux-image-generic
```

In my case, `linux-image-generic` should not be removed, since it is a metapackage that allows that my kernels get updated without my intervention whenever they becomes available. So the only two packages I should remove are `linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic`.